# python data structure with multidimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

So I have some irregular, multi-dimensional data that I'd like to be able to index by the 'age' and 'Z' value.

For each 'age', and 'Z' I have an array of 100 wavelengths and assoc'd fluxes (ex data):

```
age    = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
Z      = np.array([7,8])
waveln = np.array([np.array([a for a in arange(100)]) for b in arange(2*5)])
flux   = np.array([np.array([a*10 for a in arange(100)]) for b in arange(2*5)])
```

SO in this example, waveln[0] (an array of 100 entries) and flux[0] would get assoc'd with

```
myData['age' = 10, 'Z' = 7]['waveln'] # which I want to return the waveln array
```

and something like

```
myData['age' = 10, 'Z' = 7]['flux'] # which I want to return the flux array
```

how should I set this up?? The problem is, age and Z are both floats...

Thx,

Comment: It sounds like you might want to looking for one of the data structures available in the `pandas` library. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe Hierarchically indexed dataframes can act like multidimensional data structures. `pandas` is built on top of `numpy` so it you should be able to ease into it if you are unfamiliar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you realize the `waveln` is a 10x100 2d array, not an array of arrays?  You could construct the same with

```
np.repeat(np.arange(100)[None,:],10,axis=0)
```

If you really want `waveln` to be a 1d array containing 10 arrays, you'll have to use an alternative object dtype construction.

As defined `flux=waveln*10`, though I suspect that is just illustrative values.

But let's define `waveln` so it is more interesting - so each row is different

```
In [983]: waveln=np.arange(10)[:,None]+np.arange(100)[None,:]
```

I can construct an indexing tuple with `np.ix_` from your `Z` and `age` arrays:

```
In [984]: np.ix_(Z,age)
Out[984]: 
(array([[7],
        [8]]), array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]))

In [985]: waveln[np.ix_(Z,age)]
Out[985]: 
array([[17, 27, 37, 47, 57],
       [18, 28, 38, 48, 58]])
```

So this has selected 2 rows, and 5 columns from that.

To do `myData['age' = 10, 'Z' = 7]['waveln']`, I'd create a class with a `__getitem__` method.  `Python` converts expressions in `[]` to a tuple which is passed to this method.  But it would choke on that `=` syntax.  You can't use keyword arguments in an indexing expression.  Correct dictionary syntax is `{'age':17, 'Z':7}` or `dict(age=16, Z=12)`.

Study the `/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` file where `ix_` is defined to get ideas on how to construct a custom class.

`myData[age = 10, Z = 7, var = 'waveln')` lets you use straight function definitions.